# How can I get my EEVEE render to match my viewport lighting?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

In my animation I have a large rectangular object hidden behind a set of panels that I have keyframed to shift positions. In my viewport the rectangle appears to be affecting the face of these panels in a way that I like

[image]
Top image is the render animation - bottom image shows my viewport and the lighting I want as final.

When I render the animation that sort of ambient lighting is not present. Any ideas on why and how to get this to work properly?

- I also tried rending as a PNG sequence and when I did that all frames rendered in black and white even though my setting were in RGB (standard PNG export settings)

I am using Blender 2.8 - EEVEE - Bloom effect is on with standard settings.

Comment: Welcome Framehenge! I think you forgot to add the images to your q right?

Comment: I can see it Is it still not there?

Comment: So I figured out that if I decreased my cameras depth of view and allowed some of the background cube to show in the render, that the ambient lighting was then visible. I'm not sure why that is - almost as if because the camera couldn't see the object that it wasn't processing the volumetrics it was emitting...anyway it is kind of solved. Is there a button I should click to note "Solved"?

Comment: @Framehenge: You can post your solution as an answer, and then mark the answer as accepted. (This may sound an odd thing to do, but it’s the way things work on StackExchange sites.)

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I see no check mark option next to any of these answers...all I see it an up arrow and. a flag. Sorry for the confusion I just want to make sure I get the proper form as I move ahead as part of the community. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Framehenge: There are no answers yet, only comments. To post an answer, fill in the form at the bottom of the page and click the ‘Post Your Answer’ button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that if I decreased my cameras depth of view and allowed some of the background cube to show in the render, that the ambient lighting was then visible. I'm not sure why that is - almost as if because the camera couldn't see the object that it wasn't processing the volumetrics it was emitting